# Automate sql stored translation generation in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, resharper, resharper-6.0

I want to automate process of string localization.

Translations are stored in database.

The problem is, that to add a new localization entry, I need to complete folowing steps:

1) Open a file which stores constants with keys declaration. It looks like this :

```
public class LocalizationKeys
{
    public const string ui_btn_cancel = "ui_btn_cancel";

    public const string ui_btn_ok = "ui_btn_ok";
}
```

2) Open two sql script and add calls to stored procedures,  like :

```
exec AddLocalization(...)

exec AddTranslation(...)
```

How to automate this routine, assuming I have resharper 6.1 installed in Visual Studio 2010? I thought about macros, but not sure this is a good idea. Idealy I want to select a string hit hotkey combination enter a key name and watch how computer doing its work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ReSharper could certainly help you do that, but I'm afraid you'd need to write a small plug-in to so this. The idea would be that you would detect that the cursor is on a constant definition string literal, throw a pop-up box asking for the key, then you'd actually execute the sprocs directly from the plug-in with whatever ADO.NET/ORM you prefer.

If you do decide to go this route, you can download the ReSharper SDK [here](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/download/index.html). Also, check out the [plugin development guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6+Plugin+Development).